# CMake игнорирует выбор компилятора

Tags: cmake

Написал CMake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.0)

# set the name of the project
# must immediately follow cmake_minimum_required command

SET (CMAKE_C_COMPILER "clang.exe")
SET (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++.exe")

project (MI)

file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADER_FILES include/*.h)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES source/*.cpp)

add_library (MI source/MI.EntryPoint.cpp)

set_target_properties(MI PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
    CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
)

if(MSVC)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /std:c++17")
endif(MSVC)

target_include_directories (MI PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

add_executable (main ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries (main LINK_PUBLIC MI)
```

Вызвал команду

```
cmake ..
```

А он выбирает другой компилятор

```
$ cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.31.30818.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.31.30818.0
```

Comment: удалите временные файлы (кеш) cmake и запустите по новой.  А вообще не нужно задавать компилятор прям внутри cmake

Comment: Кэш удалял, ничего не меняется

Comment: удалите ручную установку в CMakeFiles.txt, и запускайте где то так `cmake .. -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=clang++`

Comment: Все равно не помогает

Comment: то есть, все равно выбирает другой компилятор?

Comment: Да, все равно выбирает MSVC

Comment: Похоже, что под windows оно выбирает генерировать студийный проект (если есть студия) и программист не указал параметр -G для выбора генератора.